# How to write ContinueWith methods using UnityScript in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, parse-platform, unityscript

I am having trouble with asynchronous tasks when trying to update User Data in my Parse cloud. I am using UnityScript for my project and using this function to update my Object. Please help me to write this correctly in UnityScript. I am getting this error

error: 
Unexpected token: t

expecting ), found '{'

';' expected

Insert a semicolon at the end expecting EOF, found ')'

```
gameScore.SaveAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
{
// Now let's update it with some new data.  In this case, only cheatMode 
// and score will get sent to the cloud.  playerName hasn't changed.
gameScore["cheatMode"] = true;
gameScore["score"] = 1338;
gameScore.SaveAsync(); 
});
```

Comment: Hi @JoeBlow I actually stopped working on Unity so can't confirm anything on it now.

Comment: For anyone googling here note that this issue is entirely deprecated in Unity (indeed, unityscript is deprecated!)